# After resize bitmap the result of the new bitmap is smooth bitmnap

Tags: c#

I using simple re-size method to change my bitmap to new size.
The original bitmap size is 320x240 and i change the size two times

- To 250x160
- Doing some process on the bitmap
- Change it back to 320x240

I found out that after i change it back to 320x240 i see that the bitmap is little smooth and not as i excepted.

How can i avoid this smooth to appear ?

The Resize method:

```
private static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
{

   int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
   int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

   float nPercent = 0;
   float nPercentW = 0;
   float nPercentH = 0;

   nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
   nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

   if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
      nPercent = nPercentH;
   else
      nPercent = nPercentW;

   int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
   int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

   Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
   Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
   g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

   g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
   g.Dispose();

   return (Image)b;
}
```

Comment: Scaling the image is always going to result in some lack of quality. Why would you make it smaller, and then want to change it back to the original size? It's also unclear whether you're trying to *avoid* the smoothing effect, or wondering why your image has lost quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the [HighQualityBicubic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode.aspx) interpolation mode, the image will be prefiltered and resized using the highest possible quality, resulting in the "smoothing effect".

You can try setting the [InterpolationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.interpolationmode.aspx) property to `NearestNeighbor` to obtain a "rougher" result:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image) b)) {
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i try to change the InterpolationMode - this is not helping :(

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer I wanted to post, too, since he says "How can i avoid this smooth to appear?" But obviously that was a translation error. Couldn't get a response when I asked. Anyway, +1 from me.

Answer (score 5):

The sad thing is you cannot.
When you resize your bitmap to a smaller size, information is lost. And information is interpolated from the small image (with less information) to create the new redimensionned image with the original size. It's this interpolation that gives the resulting image its smooth aspect.

To avoid this, the only thing you can do is finding a way to do the processing you have to without resizing down your image as part of your process.